# Codeception disregard specific error types and relaunch test

Tags: codeception

Is there a way to tell the system to restart the test in case a specific rare system error comes up?

Basically sometimes we get strange errors related to elements being "obscured" or "stale", but which do not mean the site is not working etc. It has to do with the site's latency I believe like CSS not loading quickly enough etc.

For example is there a directive to tell the system that if an error like

```
     [Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\ElementClickInterceptedException] Element 
\<li id="nav_step0" class="nav-steps selected"> is not clickable at point (330,237) 
because another element \<div id="ajaxloading_mask" class="mask"> obscures it
```

To simply relaunch the test again?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to relaunch failed test on specific error.

You can rerun all failed tests:

```
codecep run || codecept run -g failed
```

This command executes all tests, if any tests failed, it reruns only failed tests.